# iOS real device get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when runAction on node

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

```
- (IBAction)rotateGesture:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender {

    SKSpriteNode * face=(SKSpriteNode*)[self.skView.scene childNodeWithName:@"face_layer"];
        SKAction* action=[SKAction rotateToAngle:sender.rotation duration:0];
        
        [face runAction:action];
}
```

face is the SKSpriteNode and it is not nil (I have tested it.)
This method is called by UIRotationGestureRecognizer and there is no exception but only crashed when I make a rotation gesture on my device.
[image]

And everything is ok on simulator!!!

(My iPad mini2 also works ,too.However iPhone4 doesn't  .)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you tried using an exception breakpoint?

Comment: nothing help,thanks@ZeMoon

Comment: can you point out the exact line of code where the error occurs? See the call stack and/or post it here.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D[face runAction:action];this line. As long as I call runAction on the node ,it crashes no matter what kind of SKAction it is.Thanks a lot

Comment: @LearnCocos2D in iOS8 everything is ok,only crashed in iOS7.1

Comment: that might indicate that "face" is not a valid SKNode object, it may have been deallocated though in that case it couldn't be found by childNodeWithName in the first place. Try enabling zombies in the scheme nevertheless.

Comment: Got the same problem!!! Have you fixed that?

Comment: @serg_ov  This method is called by NSNotificationCenter and there is another SKScene  dealloced but its child named 'face_layer' is retained in other place and it register for the notification so it isn't dealloced,but this SKNode.scene property will cause BAD_ACESS beacuse the Scene has been dealloced before.  So my call : self.skView.scene is dangerous

Comment: Seems too difficult...
Some clarification: 
I dont run the action from notification method, just in didMoveToView or anywhere else
If i run  action SKAction.removeFromParent() - no crash occurs
i get that problem only if i create my SKNode in .sks file, if in code - all works with any type of action.
Also the problem occurs only on ios 7

Any ideas?